# How can I delete API as active subscriptions?

Tags: rest, soap, wso2, subscription, endpoint

I am trying to test wso2 if I can turn my soap to rest api. I follow the tutorial on youtube video call "Creating a REST API with a SOAP Back end with WSO2 API Manager". First I give full working wsdl link and I test it and get information that my wsdl is valid. But in API definition I couldnt see all my operation POST. But I continue to follow the video and subscribe my work. But I couldnt work or delete my work on store becuse I keep getting **"How can I delete API as active subscriptions?"** eror. How can I delete my api from active subscriptions?

**Update:**
The content the WSDL is saved as a resource in the /system/governance/apimgt/applicationdata/wsdls registry location. API artifacts have a dependency to this resource. Its original service address is reset to the API Gateway's address to prevent direct calls to the service endpoint. The registry permalink of the **WSDL resource is shown in the API Store and users can download and create a service out of it.**

How can I download and create a service my self?

**Update:**
In the API Subscribe secon on below under the POST I get this information, why XML cannot be generated?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- XML example cannot be generated -->
```

Comment: WSO2 API Manager does not allow to delete APIs which has active subscriptions. Since this API is created for testing purpose, is it possible to you to remove the subscription?

Comment: Thanks, I remove subscription first and then removed the API.